# ReactJS - TypeError: Apex._chartInstances.filter(...)[0] is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apexcharts

I'm trying to generate a real time graph with random values using ApexCharts in ReactJS. I have this code from this site https://apexcharts.com/react-chart-demos/line-charts/realtime/ and the graph is working correctly but whenever I navigate to other tab, I get an error that says `TypeError: Apex._chartInstances.filter(...)[0] is undefined` and the errors keep growing up. I guess that the function doesn't stop in the background when I change tabs and looks for the specified ID, fails to find it and that's why it acts like it. Any advice on how to stop the `intervals()` function before switching to another tab? This is how I call the `Progress` component in my `App`:
`

```
                          <td>SDFSDF</td>
                        </thead>
                    </table>
                </Col>
                <Progress/>
            </Row>
        </Container>
        </div>
```